# Iterating Linq result set using indexers

Tags: linq, indexer

Let's ay I have this query:

```
var results = from row in db.Table select row;
```

How can I access this:

```
string name = results[0]["columnName"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you really want a particular index you can use the *Skip()* method with *First()*.

```
var rowOffset = 0;
var results = (from row in db.Table 
               select row).Skip(rowOffset).First()["columnName"];
```

But unless you are using a *Where* clause I would really recommend using the indexer.  The indexer is pretty much a direct reference while the LINQ statement would be using the objects iterator.

Also don't forget you can do much more advanced stuff with LINQ.

```
var rowOffset = 0;
var pageLength = 10;
var results = (from row in db.Table 
               let colValue = row["columnname"]
               where colValue != null
               select colValue.ToString()
               ).Skip(rowOffset)
               .Take(pageLength)
               .ToArray();
var commaString = string.Join(", ", results);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you specifically just want the zeroth element, you can use results.First()

Answer (score 1):

`results` is a `IEnumerable` list of Rows.  So you can get it with a simple foreach.

```
foreach(var row in results)
{
   string name = row["columnName"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(from row in db.Table select row).First().columnName